# JavaScript: Round to the nearest value on a scale

Tags: javascript, math

Lets say I have a scale with 10 values between a know min and max value. How can I get the nearest value on the scale for value between min and max. Example:

```
min = 0, max = 10, value = 2.75 -> expected: value = 3
min = 5, max = 6, value = 5.12 -> expected: value = 5.1
min = 0, max = 1, value = 0.06 -> expected: value = 0.1
```

Comment: shouldn't the expected value of the last be 0.1 ?

Comment: @ahren because he wants 10 steps only between min/max

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use something like this

```js
function nearest(value, min, max, steps) {
  var zerone = Math.round((value - min) * steps / (max - min)) / steps; // bring to 0-1 range    
  zerone = Math.min(Math.max(zerone, 0), 1) // keep in range in case value is off limits
  return zerone * (max - min) + min;
}

console.log(nearest(2.75, 0, 10, 10)); // 3
console.log(nearest(5.12, 5, 6, 10)); // 5.1
console.log(nearest(0.06, 0, 1, 10)); // 0.1
```

Demo at http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/4RN37/1/

Comment: `nearest(3, 0, 10, 5); // 4 (expected 5)`
`nearest(5.2, 0, 10, 5));  // 6 (expected 5)`

Comment: @vsync `steps` hold the number of steps not the increment value. so 0 to 10 in 5 steps results in a range of 0,2,4,6,8,10. So it can never be 5

Answer (score 2):

Your scenario doesn't make much sense to me.  Why does .06 round to 1 and not .1 but 5.12 rounds to 5.1 with the same scale (1 integer)?  It's confusing.

Either way, if you want to round to a precise # of decimal places, check this out:
http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/round.shtml

```
var original=28.453

1) //round "original" to two decimals
var result=Math.round(original*100)/100  //returns 28.45

2) // round "original" to 1 decimal
var result=Math.round(original*10)/10  //returns 28.5

3) //round 8.111111 to 3 decimals
var result=Math.round(8.111111*1000)/1000  //returns 8.111
```

With this tutorial, you should be able to do exactly what you want.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, I've update the question. Unfortunately you totally miss the point of the question. Its not about rounding to a specific decimal precision. But to find the nearest value on scale.

Comment: Your definition of a "scale" is still not well defined.  Why are the items between 5 and 6 not simply an integer: 5 or 6.  Why does 1-10 round to integers and not 2.7 or 2.8 (depending if you round 5 up or down)?  IMO, what you really need is: min, max, and step.  step, defining how to divide up the rest of the space.

Comment: What I meant was 10 values between 5 and 6 so the values are 5, 5.1, 5.2 and so on. So you have always a defined count of steps between min and max value. Sorry for my improper english.

Comment: ah, now I understand.  So if your range was 5 to 7 then it would divide 5 to 7 into 10 intervals?  If so, then I now understand and I agree that what I suggested won't help you there.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps more comprehensible:

```
var numberOfSteps = 10;
var step = (max - min) / numberOfSteps;
var difference = start - min;
var stepsToDifference = Math.round(difference / step);
var answer = min + step * stepsToDifference;
```

This also allows you to change the number of steps in your sequence.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest something like that :

```
var step = (max - min) / 10;
return Math.round(value / step) * step;
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the problem where I was getting `5.7999997` instead of the weanted `5.8` for example. Here was my first fix (for java...).

```
public static float nearest(float val, float min, float max, int steps) {
    float step = (max - min) / steps;
    float diff = val - min;
    float steps_to_diff = round(diff / step);
    float answer = min + step * steps_to_diff;
    answer = ((int) (answer * steps)) / (float) steps;
    return answer;
}
```

However using this on `nearest(6.5098, 0, 10, 1000)` I would get `6.509` instead of the wanted `6.51`.
This solved it for me (watch out for overflows when values are really large):

```
public static float nearest(float val, float min, float max, int steps) {
    val *= steps;
    min *= steps;
    max *= steps;
    float step = (max - min) / steps;
    float diff = val - min;
    float steps_to_diff = round(diff / step);
    float answer = min + step * steps_to_diff;
    return answer / (float) steps;
}
```

Comment: The scaling on your second code block solves the floating point issues I was having. I was getting values like `5.300000000000001` with the accepted answer, but with this I get `5.3` as expected.

Answer (score 0):

```
var step = 10;
return Math.ceil(x / step) * step;
```